# Typescript variable to Hold Jquery reference to HTML5 Canvas

Tags: typescript

Hi I am wondering if I am doing this the correct way, I want to have a Typescript variable to Hold Jquery reference to HTML5 Canvas. I have an untyped canvas object that is passed into the constructor from the line in $(document).ready.

game.ts:

```
///<reference path="../javascripts/sprite.js" />
///<reference path="d.ts/jquery-1.8.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.js/>


        $(document).ready(function () {
        canvas = $('#canvas');

        })
    });

class Game {

    canvas;

    CANVAS_WIDTH: number;
    CANVAS_HEIGHT: number;

    constructor (canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width();
        this.CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height();
    }
```

However I don't get any jquery syntax auto-completion like with .width() when using this canvas variable in the game class;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution, Use the JQuery variable:

```
class Game {

     canvas : JQuery;

    CANVAS_WIDTH: number;
    CANVAS_HEIGHT: number;

    constructor (canvas:JQuery) {
        this.canvas = canvas;

        this.CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width();
        this.CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

An even better way to do things (using the HTMLCanvasElement type), although losing the width() property is to refer to the Canvas like so.

```
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas');

context2D: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
```